# Почему метод focusWidget() не видит объект, который в фокусе?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Метод `focusWidget()` класса `QApplication` возвращает ссылку на объект, находящийся в фокусе. При запуске программы в объекте (`QLineEdit`) мигает курсор и можно вводить данные, т. е. насколько я понял, объект в фокусе. Почему тогда `app.focusWidget()` возвращает `None`?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QLineEdit, QApplication)


class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        qle = QLineEdit(self)
        qle.move(60, 100)

        print("app.focusWidget(): ", app.focusWidget())
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 280, 170)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Возвращается `None` потому что на момент работы `print(...` никаких виджетов на экране ещё нет. Они появятся только после `ex.show()`, во время работы `app.exec_()`

Чтобы печатать, какой виджет в фокусе во время работы, можно запустить таймер, например дописав в конструкторе или initUI:

```
timer = QTimer(self);
timer.timeout.connect(lambda: print("app.focusWidget(): ", app.focusWidget()))
timer.start(1000);
```

Comment: можно проще: `QTimer.singleShot(1000, lambda: print("app.focusWidget(): ", app.focusWidget()))`